# python distance comparison within a list

Tags: python

I have a location list and want to compare each location with the others to eliminate close locations. Here, the "close" means is that 20km. If the distance between any location is greater than "close", should be added into the result list as a far enough location. I have done this to compare each location with other locations in the list. But, i think i am missing some distance comparisons. So, any help would be great.

Let me give you an example about what i want to achieve and where i got stuck. 
For example, `location_list=[A,B,C,D,E,F]`, the first comparison pairs would be `(A,B)` and distance between them is 25km. So, it is greater than threshold, we can add `A,B` to result list.
The second comparison would be `(A,C)` and distance between them is 50km that is greater than threshold, here i should compare C with A and B which are previously added to result list. If the distance between `(B,C)` is greater than threshold, i should add `C` to the result list, otherwise C should not be added to the list, because it is close to the previously added locations.

The point i got stuck is this, how can I compare the new location `(e.g., C)` with `(A,B)` which are added to the list in previous step.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    # convert decimal degrees to radians
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    km = 6367 * c
    return km


result=[]
location_list=[(44.968046,-94.420307),
                (44.33328,-89.132008),
                (33.755787,-116.359998),
                (33.844843,-116.54911),
                (44.92057,-93.44786),
                (44.240309,-91.493619),
                (44.968041,-94.419696),
                (44.333304,-89.132027),
                (33.755783,-116.360066),
                (33.844847,-116.549069),
                (44.920474,-93.447851),
                (44.240304,-91.493768)]


for j in location_list:
    for k in location_list:
        if haversine(j[0],j[1],k[0],k[1])>20:
            print j,k,haversine(j[0],j[1],k[0],k[1])
            result.append(j[0],j[1])
            result.append(k[0],k[1])
```

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.combinations(location_list, 2)` to generate each pair of locations exactly once - it will simplify your life :-)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what results you want. Do you want "all the points that have no other points within 20km" or "a set of points that are not within 20km of each other". The first set is unique, but to find it you'll need to test every combination of points (unless you go for a more complicated space-partitioning approach). The second sentence is either to solve, but it may describe multiple sets of points (BenS's answer finds one that favors points early in the input). For example, in a 1-D case, the points `[0, 25, 35, 60]` can be solved with either `[0, 25, 60]` or [0, 35, 60]`.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would seem to be to replace the inner loop with one that checks against all previous points in the list, and adds the new point to the list only if it is the necessary distance away.

```
for j in location_list:
    is_distant_location = True

    # Check against all previously accepted points.
    # If it's too close, don't accept it.
    for n in result:
        if haversine(j[0],j[1],n[0],n[1]) <= 20:
            is_distant_location = False
            break

    if is_distant_location:
        result.append(j[0],j[1])
```

There are probably more advanced tools that could give you more concise code that - once you're used to the tools - might be easier to maintain, like the `itertools` module that Tim Peters suggested.

Comment: it produces only one result, did i miss something?

Comment: No, I did - there was a typo in the original code that I have now corrected. I've tested it on my end and it seems to be working now.

Comment: But, it seem to be working incorrectly. The distance between these locations is  less than 20km. But, you program includes these in the result this why? .(33.755783,-116.360066),(33.844847,-116.549069),

Comment: I'm confused because when I enter `haversine(33.755783,-116.360066,33.844847,-116.549069)`, I get `21.460781...`. Incidentally, are you sure that's the right order? I don't think it matters in this case because I get `haversine(-116.360066,33.755783,-116.549069,33.844847) == 20.064034...`, but in the code the parameters of `haversine` are `lon1` and then `lat1`, but the call seems to pass the latitude value and then the longitude value.